# Extract schema from JSON data in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have below JSON schema which works ok with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`. I am able to extract schema directly from it but when it comes to JSON Data string, then I am not sure how to extract schema.

```html
{
"fields": [
 {
  "name": "approved",
  "type": "Boolean",
  "displayName": "Approved",
  "isNullable": true,
  "isSearchable": false,
  "isFilter": true,
  "isInternal": false
 }
     ]
}
```

In the above JSON, `approved` is the field name so I am able to extract schema, but I have a JSON data string as below and want to extract schema from it.

```html
{
 "skuId": "1",
 "balance": [
  {
   "warehouseId": "1_1",
   "warehouseName": "Main Warehouse",
   "totalQuantity": 1000001,
   "reservedQuantity": 1,
   "hasUnlimitedQuantity": true,
   "timeToRefill": null,
   "dateOfSupplyUtc": null
  }
    ]
}
```

In the above example JSON data, `warehouseid`, `warehousename`, etc., are fieldname and I need to have those in my schema in c#.

Can anyone please suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a new class, copy your json data string, and in visual studio  click edit -> paste special, and it will create classes that you can deserialize to the way you want.

You are missing the closing ']' so that needs to be addressed first.

If you use a dictionary and need to iterate it :

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in myDictionary) { // do something with entry.Value or entry.Key }
```

Comment: Corrected missing "]". However, paste special in this case will not help as it will create property for field name itself such as `warehouseid`, `warehousename`, etc. I do not want that.

Comment: Will deserializing balance to Dictionary<string,string> work for you? You can access it as dictionary[key]

Comment: I am trying with `Dictionary<string, dynamic>`, but wondering how can I loop through each field to get those.

Comment: foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in myDictionary) { // do something with entry.Value or entry.Key }

Comment: Looping through `KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>` and then loop through `Dictionary<string, dynamic>` has helped. Also based on above JSON data string, I had to use `Dictionary<string, dynamic>.KeyCollection`. Thanks for your help.